# python logging string formatting

Tags: python, logging, formatting, string-formatting

I am using python's log [formatter](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) to format [log records](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) and i have a fmt value of

```
fmt = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s"
```

What i would like is that "[file.py:20]" to be stretched to 10 characters wide (for example). If it was one value that would have been easy but is there any way to stretch this entire structure to a specified length?
I want something like:

```
tmp = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s]"
fmt = "%(tmp)10s %(message)s"
```

I would like to know if this is possible using string formatting or if I can trick python's formatter somehow to get what i want..

Comment: No.  It's not possible without subclassing the Formatter to create a new kind of formatter.  How important is this to you?

Comment: I would spend about 1-2 hours to get it working (although i'm a bit newbish). I assume i would have to override the format method and inject a custom attribute in the LogRecord object?

Comment: Is 10 chars a _minimum_ width? i.e. if the string is longer than 10 chars do you want to truncate it?

Comment: not really important but lets say don't truncate it

Comment: I find myself surprised that I cannot use .ljust() in this case. Did the string stop being a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option 1

Start here: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#formatter-objects

You'll create your own customized subclass of `Formatter` that provides it's own unique `format` method.

Then you must be sure to call `setFormatter()` in each of your `Handlers` so that they use your new formatter.

Option 2

Create your own subclass of LogRecord with the additional property.

Subclass `Logger` and override `makeRecord` to create your new subclass of `LogRecord`.

Provide a customized format that uses this new property value.

Answer (score 13):

As an example, this Formatter ensures a fixed width `"[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s]"` by either truncating the filename, or right-padding (after the line number) with spaces.

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    width = 10

    def format(self, record):
        max_filename_width = self.width - 3 - len(str(record.lineno))
        filename = record.filename
        if len(record.filename) > max_filename_width:
            filename = record.filename[:max_filename_width]
        a = "%s:%s" % (filename, record.lineno)
        return "[%s] %s" % (a.ljust(self.width), record.msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = MyFormatter()
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)

    logger.debug('No one expects the spammish repetition')
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to ensure a *minimum* width of 10 characters, ditch the filename stuff.

```
def format(self, record):
    a = "%s:%s" % (record.filename, record.lineno)
    return "[%s] %s" % (a.ljust(self.width), record.msg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using @rob-cowie's answer as a basis, I've found the following useful:

```
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    width = 24
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

    def format(self, record):
        cpath = '%s:%s:%s' % (record.module, record.funcName, record.lineno)
        cpath = cpath[-self.width:].ljust(self.width)
        record.message = record.getMessage()
        s = "%-7s %s %s : %s" % (record.levelname, self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt), cpath, record.getMessage())
        if record.exc_info:
            # Cache the traceback text to avoid converting it multiple times
            # (it's constant anyway)
            if not record.exc_text:
                record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
        if record.exc_text:
            if s[-1:] != "\n":
                s = s + "\n"
            s = s + record.exc_text
        #if record.stack_info:
        #    if s[-1:] != "\n":
        #        s = s + "\n"
        #    s = s + self.formatStack(record.stack_info)
        return s

logFormatter = MyFormatter()
logger = logging.getLogger("example")
logger.setFormatter(logFormatter)
```

Which gives output like:

```
WARNING 2014-03-28 16:05:09 module:function:31       : Message
WARNING 2014-03-28 16:05:09 dule:longerfunctions:140 : Message
```

Comment: Exception occurred when logger.setFormatter(logFormatter): AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'setFormatter'