# Python logging formatting by level

Tags: python, logging

I'm using python's logging library, but I want the debug logs to have a different format than the warning and error logs. Is this possible?

ETA: I want warnings and errors to appear as:

```
%(levelname)s: %(message)s
```

but debug statements to appear as

```
DEBUG: (only Brian cares about this) : %(message)s
```

all other questions I've seen have been to change the format, but that changes for EVERYTHING.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python logging string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692248/python-logging-string-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **double-check if you really need this. A log output with different record formats is prone to be rather hard to read by both humans and machines.**
Maybe what you actually need is different formats for different log destinations (console vs file) which will also have different verbosity (the file will have a debug log with additional information).

Now, the way is to use a custom `Formatter`:

```
class MultiformatFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self,<args>):
        <...>
    def format(self,record):
        if record.levelno <= logging.DEBUG:
            s=<generate string one way>
        else:
            s=<generate string another way>
        return s
<...>
#for each handler that this should apply to
handler.setFormatter(MultiformatFormatter(<args>))
```